# Restore Windows Search with Google Desktop Search installed

Tags: windows-7, windows-search, google-desktop-search

I have a win7 laptop with Google Desktop installed.

I like to use BOTH windows search AND google desktop for their differing results due to my nack of losing files.

However, Google Desktop has replaced Windows Search on the "Search Everything" option on the start menu and I can't find out how to restore WIndows Search.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Step 1][image: Step 2]

And, if you can remember enough of the file name, try **[Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/)**—very fast.